# Friction losses

Tags: fluid-mechanics

> - Water is pumped from a reservoir to storage tank atop a building by means of a centrifugal There is a 200 ft difference in elevation between the two surfaces The inlet pipe at the reservoir is 8.0 ft below the surface and local conditions are such that level is constant.
> - The storage tank is vented to the atmosphere the liquid level is maintained constant.
> - The inlet pipe to the storage tank is 6.0 ft below the surface.
> - The piping consists of 200 ft of 6 in Sch 40 steel pipe containing 90 elbows and one open gate valve from the reservoir to pump.
> - 6 in pipe follows the pump for a length of 75 after which the pipe size is reduced to 4 in Sch 40 steel for 250 ft to the tank.
> - The 4 in pipe contains one gate and three 90 elbows.
> - It is desired to maintain a flow water into the tank of 625 gal min.
> - Water temperature 68°F If the pump motor set has an overall efficiency 60%.
> - What would the pumping costs be in dollars a day if electricity costs 0.02 kWh?

For this problem, I accounted the following as the sources of frictional loss.

1. frictional shear stress and skin friction of both pipes
2. sudden expansion from the pipe to the second tank
3. sudden contraction from the reservoir to the pipe and from the first type of pipe to the second
4. valves and fittings installed in the piping system

Are there any sources of frictional loss from the given problem that I should or should not include?

Comment: Did you copy the question correctly? A centrifugal what?

Comment: @SolarMike, sorry, it is a centrifugal pump.